# I would really like to know why 53.0 is returned when 5.0 should be returned here for charAt(0). 52.0 is returned instead of 4.0 for charAt(1)?

Tags: java, return-value

this is the test class in which I'm printing out the value of result because it is wrong and would like to solve it first, if postfix.charAt(0) was printed out here, which I've tried I do get 5, but that's not the problem:

```
public class TestClass {
public String postfix = "54+" //the string as you can see charAt(0) is 5 and charAt(1) is 4
@Before 
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    }

@After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    }
@Test
public void testEasyEvaluatePostfixExpression() throws InvalidNotationFormatException, StackOverflowException, StackUnderflowException {
        double result = Notation.evaluatePostfixExpression(postfix); //assigns result to what is returned by calling the class Notation's evaluatePostfixExpression method passing the String postfix as parameter
        System.out.println(result); //simply prints out result which is postfixEpr.charAt(0)
        assertEquals(evalEasyPostfix, result, .001); //this should fail which it does anyway
    }
}
```

This is the class to be tested it returns the wrong data when returning postfixExpr.charAt(0) here  53.0 is displayed which does not exist anywhere :0:

```
public class Notation {
public static double evaluatePostfixExpression(String postfixExpr)
            throws InvalidNotationFormatException, StackOverflowException, StackUnderflowException {

            return Double.valueOf(postfixExpr.charAt(0)); //when I change return type to String and change result to string also I get "54+" which is what is expected the charAt() value is what is wrong.
            
    }
}``
```

Comment: Have a look at the [ASCII Table](https://www.asciitable.com/). Can you spot, what might cause the behaviour you are seeing?

Comment: The result of `charAt` is return a `char`.  There is no `Double.valueOf(char)`, instead it's been treated as the numeric representation of the character (on the ASCII table)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

`charAt()` returns a `char` primitive which is being treated as its associated ascii number by `Double.valueOf()`. Try converting the `char` to a string with `Character.toString()` first, or just use the `substring` method.

https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:ASCII-Table-wide.svg

https://beginnersbook.com/2019/04/java-char-to-string-conversion/